# Intermittent "The operation timed out" error on production server

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I have a web API(service) whose target framework is .net core 2.0.

This service is calling a custom identity server 4 endpoint using HttpClient by using the 'using' statement. This call always works fine on the development/UAT server. 
But on all production servers, it fails intermittently and throws the following exception:

> One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while sending the
>   request.) Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. (An error occurred while sending the request.) --->
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The operation
>   timed out    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()    at
>   System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.d__105.MoveNext()    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)    at Get(String a, String b)

I went through related stack-overflow posts, some suggested making HttpClient static as it might throw socket exhaustion error. But I am not getting that error either I am able to reproduce this issue on a development server. I created a console application and called this service 64k times, but still, it worked properly.

[How to stop outbound HTTP connections from timing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56386560/how-to-stop-outbound-http-connections-from-timing-out)

[Asp.net Core HttpClient has many TIME_WAIT or CLOSE_WAIT connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931543/asp-net-core-httpclient-has-many-time-wait-or-close-wait-connections)

Can someone please tell me, what can be the reason for this intermittent error only on the production server or is there any way I can reproduce this issue on the dev server. I have tried by making many calls to service, but still unable to reproduce the error.

Comment: you can try adding a retry logic for this type of exception.

Comment: But the user is trying continuously, it fails by throwing same exception only.

Comment: On production there is a different network ? Maybe the router ? Firewall ? Nat ?

Comment: it could be a case of the existing instances are not able to take the load and hence you need to scale up or throttle requests to certain limit. or it could be case of request being rejected by azure as it may have resembled a DDOS attack.

Comment: @PurnimaNaik Is your production environment is a load-balanced environment?