# Reuse httpClient created via the HttpClientFactory in different methods of the same class? (C# / .NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient, httpclientfactory

I have a class into which the `IHttpClientFactory` is injected via the constructor. There's also a `HttpClient` private field in this class.

Are there any issues with creating the `HttpClient` in the constructor, using the factory, and then reusing that `HttpClient` in two/multiple methods within that one class to make two/multiple different api calls? (Same Api, different endpoints)

Or would it be better to use the factory in each method to create a new client. What are the implications/pros & cons of each approach? Is any one inherently better or doesn't it matter?

```cs
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

public RestClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
   _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
}

public async Task<SomeResponse> Method1(SomeRequest request)
{
    ...

        using (var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
        {
             httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
                    httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(jsonBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            using (var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage))
            {
                ...
            }
        }
...
}

public async Task<SomeOtherResponse> Method2(someInput)
{
   ...

        using (var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri.ToString()))
        {
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Accept", "image/png");
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);

            using (var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage))
            {
                ...
            }
        }
...
}
```

---

Edit: have looked at this post [Should I cache and reuse HttpClient created from HttpClientFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54597303/should-i-cache-and-reuse-httpclient-created-from-httpclientfactory) but it doesn't answer my questions. If there is something to be derived from there please explain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I cache and reuse HttpClient created from HttpClientFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54597303/should-i-cache-and-reuse-httpclient-created-from-httpclientfactory)

Comment: No still don't understand if it's okay to create the httpClient in the constructor and reuse it, the example in the Basic usage (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2) only has one method in the class and it creates the httpClient in that.

Comment: It is ok to create the `HttpClient` in the constructor and reuse it.

Comment: I think it is okay to use the factory to create new clients when you need them (not disagreeing with the above - just saying I don't see a problem using the client factory whenever you need a client). It is difficult to say if one is better than the other. I prefer to use the client factory because this is what MS recommends (at least for now - until they change their mind again). I don't see any cons that way.

Comment: Having looked at the attached link again, it's relevance now makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this guidance from Microsoft: [Guidelines for using HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines)

I copy here the related part

> ### Recommended use
>
> #### In .NET Core and .NET 5+:
>
> Use a `static` or *singleton* `HttpClient` instance with `PooledConnectionLifetime` set to the desired interval, such as two minutes, depending on expected DNS changes. This solves both the socket exhaustion and DNS changes problems without adding the overhead of `IHttpClientFactory`. If you need to be able to mock your handler, you can register it separately.
>
> Using `IHttpClientFactory`, you can have multiple, differently configured clients for different use cases. However, be aware that the factory-created clients are intended to be short-lived, and once the client is created, the factory no longer has control over it.
>
> The factory pools `HttpMessageHandler` instances, and, if its lifetime hasn't expired, a handler can be reused from the pool when the factory creates a new `HttpClient` instance. This reuse avoids any socket exhaustion issues.
>
> If you desire the configurability that `IHttpClientFactory` provides, we recommend using the typed-client approach.
>
> #### In .NET Framework:
>
> Use `IHttpClientFactory` to manage your `HttpClient` instances. If you create a new client instance for each request, you can exhaust available sockets.
>
> #### Tip
>
> If your app requires cookies, consider disabling automatic cookie handling or avoiding `IHttpClientFactory`. Pooling the `HttpMessageHandler` instances results in sharing of `CookieContainer` objects. Unanticipated `CookieContainer` object sharing often results in incorrect code.

Comment: "However, be aware that the factory-created clients are intended to be short-lived" this is what I was looking for, I take this to mean that while they CAN be reused, probably shouldn't be too many times. Can anyone expand on this/exactly why this is? Thank you for posting the relevant snippet, easy to miss in a long article.

Comment: @imsan The Factory itself manages a handler pool. A handler can be used by only a single instance of HttpClient. If your HttpClient instances are short-lived then the underlying handlers could be reused for new instances.

Comment: @imsan If you are interested about the internals [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73838672/13268855) you can read more about them.